# kendo ui AngularJS Grid CRUD operations

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to implement the popup editor for kendo ui grid with angularjs. Edit of my record works just fine but Adding a new record seems to be sending data-value-field as [object Object]. I just can't seem to figure that out.

Here is my data source in controller:

```
$scope.tempDataSource = '[{"value": 7,"text": "fdsdd - dsfdsfdsf"},{"value": 6,"text": "sads - sadsa"},{"value": 5,"text": "dsf - dsfdsf"},{"value": 2,"text": "dsf - sdfdsfds"}]';
```

and here is my dropdown list:

```
<input name="AppName"
                   data-bind="value:projId"
                   data-value-field="value"
                   data-text-field="text"
                   data-source="{{tempDataSource}}"
                   data-role="dropdownlist" />
```

As I mentioned, Grid record edit works just fine. It is an add record which sends value as [object Object]

Comment: can you add your add record function please

Answer (score 0):

Why are you passing string? Can you try it like this:

```
$scope.tempDataSource = [{"value": 7,"text": "fdsdd - dsfdsfdsf"},{"value": 6,"text": "sads - sadsa"},{"value": 5,"text": "dsf - dsfdsf"},{"value": 2,"text": "dsf - sdfdsfds"}];
```

and in html:

```
<input name="AppName"
                   data-bind="value:projId"
                   data-value-field="value"
                   data-text-field="text"
                   data-source="tempDataSource"
                   data-role="dropdownlist" />
```

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21130121. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a quick reply, I will immediately this comment here.